# In Angular 9 how to force the property date type in the http client response model?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on Angular 9 project, and one of the responses I'm receiving contains a property of type `Date`, but when I send a request:

```
// MyModel
class MyModel {
   prop: string;
   myDate: Date;
}

// request sent like
this.http.get<MyModel>(url);
```

The response comes correctly but the property is filled as a `string` ISO format (e.g: `2020-11-24T19:48:20.3637502`) (because in JSON there's no type for `Date`).
Whay I need is that when ever I create an instance of `MyModel` or assign value to `myDate` property to be always a `Date`.

Is there a way to do this other than doing a `map` after receiving the response?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
class MyModel {
   prop: string;
   private _myDate: Date;
   public get myDate() {
      return this._myDate;
   };
   public set myDate(val) {
      this._myDate = new Date(val);
   };
}
```

Comment: In which format do you receive the date ?

Comment: is ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way is to map the returned data and make the modification manually.

```
this.httpClient.get<DataModel>("/api/getData")
  .pipe(
    map((data)=>{
      data.date1 = new Date(data.date1);
      data.date2 = new Date(data.date2);
      data.date3 = new Date(data.date3);
      return data;
    })
  );
```

Note that I'm cheating a bit - Date constructor can take both string and Date as a parameter. In general, the result of mapping step can have different type than received response.

Alternatively, you can use an Http interceptor.

See [Date Handling in Angular Application (Part 2 - Angular Http Client and Ngx Datepicker)](https://dev.to/imben1109/date-handling-in-angular-application-part-2-angular-http-client-and-ngx-datepicker-3fna)

Additionally, as you noticed, the type you specify for the http get is not enforced in any way. You receive the result of a json deserialization.

Note that this is particularly tricky if you use a `class`, not a `type` as your data model. Even in case the fields you receive are what you expect, the prototype chain is not established, so any method call on received object will result in a runtime error.

This also explains why your attempt with `get` and `set` failed - the object you receive in not an instance of `MyModel` class.

My advise is to

- model the response data as a `type` (or `interface`)
- transform the data if needed via Observable.pipe
- if you need a class as a data model, map the response to a class in the previous step.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate for me what do you mean exactly by "model the response data as a `type` (or `interface`)" ?

Comment: I mean `type MyModel` or `interface MyModel` instead of `class MyModel`. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131898/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class-in-typescript