# Map HTTP response 1 or 0 to boolean

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript interface, which is used to map data from a HTTP response:

```
interface Person {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   active: boolean;
}
```

Here's the sample response:

```
{
       firstName: 'John',
       lastName: 'Brown',
       active: 1;
}
```

Here's the logic used to store the response into a local variable:

```
const person: Person = response;
```

The following provides the same result:

```
const person = response as Person;
```

Based on the logic described above, the person object results in the following:

```
{
       firstName: 'John',
       lastName: 'Brown',
       active: 1;
}
```

The problem is the the 'active' property is expected to be a boolean, true or false, not an integer.

Any ideas how to address this issue?

Note that checking the value and converting it is not a viable option because the response could be an array of a hundred objects and I would not want to traverse them.

Also, the backend can not be changed to pass true or false in the response.  The response must contain a 1 or 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247727/how-to-automatically-convert-yyyy-mm-dd-strings-from-http-responses-to-date?noredirect=1#comment129360762_73247727

Comment: `as Person` is just a type assertion, by the way, **not** a cast or conversion. Fortunately for you if you don't want to do either of the right things it'll work anyway, because 1 is truth-y and 0 is false-y.

Comment: "the response could be an array of a hundred objects and I would not want to traverse them" Why not? 100 is small, just `arr.map(conversionFunction)` should do it.  Either you have to just put up with whatever the data looks like (e.g., change your interface to accept `0 | 1` instead of `boolean`) or you have to convert the data, even if there's lots of data.  What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at Typescript Enums not booleans all together but a workaround

Comment: @jonrsharpe that makes sense.  But, is there a way to just have true and false, not 1 or 0?

Comment: @jcalz I don't want to traverse the data because it is part of a pageable query from the server side.  So, the logic could be invoked many times as a user pages through the data.  So, I would like to avoid having to loop through 100 rows every time the user goes to another page, just to translate the column, if possible.

Comment: Not without the two options you've ruled out. Either you have to convert the value for each item, or fix the API.

Comment: Either you don't translate the column or you do translate the column.  If you don't translate the column then you should change your interface to use `0 | 1`.  If you do translate the column then you'll have to do it once per row.  I am almost certain that doing `!!x` once per row is not going to be a performance problem, and if it is, your app is doing something unreasonable.  Are you not already doing calculations once per row?  Can you *demonstrate* that there would be a problem if you do that?

Comment: Thanks for the input.   I would prefer to use the boolean data type, with true and false values.  You have provided options for me to explore.  @jcalz I will perform some tests to confirm any performance issue and proceed based on those results.